# Recursion in an ER diagram

Tags: recursion, entity-relationship

Is it reasonable to use a recursive relationship in an ER-diagram? I've made an example below:

[image]

For instance, if a customer orders 3 fish dishes, 3 chips and 2 drinks, where each fish dish itself consist of 1 fish and 2 vegetables which themselves are menu items, and so on:

```
group1          : fish_dish_group(3), chips(3), drinks(2)
fish_dish_group : fish(1), vegetable_group(2)
vegetable_group : vegetable_1, vegetable_2
```

However, is such a relationship even permissible, as `grouping` and `food` are different types? I would think not, so what are the alternatives to recursive relationships?

Answer (score 0):

an entity type can have a relation with it self and this is absolutely valid in ER.  in your example, an alternative can be introducing a secondery entity type "sub-group" and link it to the original "group" by an n:m relationship.